# Comma with "for example" in a parenthetical

Tags: punctuation

> Other vegetarian animals, giraffes and rhinoceroses for example, help
>   as well.

Do I have to put a comma before "for example" like this:

> Other vegetarian animals, giraffes and rhinoceroses, for example, help
>   as well.

or is putting comma just optional?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* put a comma there, but it may be better if you don't. The phrase is already within a comma-separated parenthetical clause ("giraffes and rhinoceroses for example"), so it's just qualifying what it mentions as examples; the lack of an extra comma ties it more closely and reduces possible confusion about where the parenthetical ends.

If you do put a comma there, consider changing the outer comma pair to something different, like dashes or parentheses:

1. > Other vegetarian animals (giraffes and rhinoceroses, for example) help as well.
2. > Other vegetarian animals — giraffes and rhinoceroses, for example — help as well.